# Using Interface to call values from Fragment to Activity caused by ClassCastException

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment

I would like to use interface to implement the communicate of passing data from fragments to activity's button which contains onClick event. I can see Map can write the data which is valid on editText field, but those values cannot be sent to activity. it shows error and stopped once I trigger the onClick event on activity.

The procedures are:

1. Users filled in the editText field
2. Once the editText field is out-focused, the TextWatcher with validation will check (If invalid, editText will not put into HashMap and hint user to edit, if user click submit button, it will reheat user change the correct answer at first)
3. When user filled all fields and click button, values on fragments will return as Hashmap, and checking it has null fields or not, and explode the values and putExtra() to next activity.

I was confused on the usage of the interface although I have read many sources and cases during troubleshooting this issue. Or May I use another solution to implement this function?

Thanks for any assistance.

[image: Calling Fragments' Map to activity]

Main activity:

```
......
Fragment_step_1 getHashMapStep1 = new Fragment_step_1();
Fragment_step_2 getHashMapStep2 = new Fragment_step_2();

public interface onPassValue{
    public Map<Object, String> onPassValueStep1(Map<Object, String> insureApplicant);
}

public interface onPassValue2{
    Map<Object, String> onPassValueStep2(Map<Object, String> insureApplicant2);
}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ......
    btn_sendInsureInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){

            Fragment_step_1.onPassValueStep1();
            Fragment_step_2.onPassValueStep2();
            //NullPointerException on those two calling interface method
            ......
        }
}
......
```

Fragment_step_1: (xxx is activity's name)

```
public class Fragment_step_1 extends Fragment implements xxx.onPassValue {
    ......
     Map<Object, String> insureApplicant = new HashMap<>(4);

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context xxx){
    super.onAttach(xxx);

    try {
       passValue = (onPassValue) xxx;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(pingan_insure_info.toString()
                + " didn't implement onPassValue");
    }
    //THROW EXCEPTION ALWAYS
}

@Override
public Map<Object, String> onPassValueStep1(Map<Object, String> insureResult) {
    for (Object key : insureResult.entrySet()) {
        //System.out.println(key + " fragment_1 : " + insureResult.get(key));
        System.out.println(" fragment_1 : " + key);
        Log.e("map", String.valueOf(insureResult));
    }
    return insureResult;
}
    ......
```

Fragment_step_2: (xxx is activity's name)

```
public class Fragment_step_2 extends Fragment implements xxx.onPassValue2{
......
RelativeLayout correspondence;
HashMap insureApplicant2 = new HashMap<>(3);

@Override
public void onAttach(Context xxx){
    super.onAttach(xxx);

    try {
        passValueStep2 = (onPassValueStep2) xxx;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(xxx.toString()
                + " didn't implement onPassValue");
    }
    //THROW EXCEPTION ALWAYS
}

@Override
public Map<Object, String> onPassValueStep2(Map<Object, String> insureApplicantStep2){
    for (Object key : insureApplicantStep2.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("fragment_2 : " + key);
        Log.e("Hashmap2", String.valueOf(insureApplicantStep2));
    }
    return insureApplicant2;
}
```

All fragments' editText will be filled after the editText is valid and typing by user and send to the function and stored in HashMap.

For example: (AddTextChangedListener with TextWatcher)

```
residentAddress.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            residentAddress.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener(){
                @Override
                public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean isFocus){
                    if(!isFocus){
                        if("".trim().equals(residentAddress.getText().toString())){
                            rAddress.setError("Resident Address is required.");
                            strAddress = "";
                            insureApplicant2.put(2, strAddress);
                        } else {
                            rAddress.setErrorEnabled(false);
                            rAddress.setError(null);
                            strAddress = residentAddress.getText().toString().trim();
                            insureApplicant2.put(2, strAddress);

                            onPassValueStep2(insureApplicant2);
                            //CAN PUT THE VALUE TO HASHMAP BUT CANNOT be RETURNED TO ACTIVITY :(
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

To pass values from fragment to activity create interface in fragment.not in activity.

### Fragment A

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

    public interface InterfaceTest{
        void passValue(String passval);
    }

    InterfaceTest interfaceTest;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);


        interfaceTest= (InterfaceTest) context;


    }

    public FragmentA() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_, container, false);



        return  rootView;

    }
//
    public void passToActivity(){
        interfaceTest.passValue("yourvalues");
    }

}
```

### ACTIVITY

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentA.InterfaceTest {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //create code for add fragment in activity


    }

    @Override
    public void passValue(String passval) {
        Log.e("print",passval);
    }
}
```